# Automorphisms of Cayley graphs of $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, cayley-graphs

My goal is to show that there are no finite generating sets $A$ and $B$ such that $\mathrm{Cay}(\mathbb{Z},A)$ is isomorphic to $\mathrm{Cay}(\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}_2, B)$. My idea for this is to start by noting that $\mathrm{Cay}(\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}_2, B)$ has a non-trivial automorphism of order $2$ with exactly two fixed vertices, induced by the map $(a,b) \mapsto (-a,b)$.

Then I have the feeling that there should be no such automorphism of $\mathrm{Cay}(\mathbb{Z},A)$. This is obvious if we pick the generating set $A = \{1\}$; in this case $\mathrm{Cay}(\mathbb{Z},A)$ is just the real line and if a graph automorphism has two fixed vertices then it is trivial. However, this is less clear when the generating set for $\mathbb{Z}$ is $\{n_1, \dots, n_k\}$ with $\gcd(n_1, \dots, n_k) = 1$.

Can anyone provide a proof that an automorphism of $\mathrm{Cay}(\mathbb{Z},A)$ with two fixed points must be trivial, or provide a counterexample? Different approaches to my original problem are also welcome.

**Edit.** Some clarifications: my question is exactly as formulated in kabenyuk's comment. I want to show that there are no generating sets $A$ of $\mathbb{Z}$ and $B$ of $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ such that the Cayley graphs $\mathrm{Cay}(\mathbb{Z},A)$ and $\mathrm{Cay}(\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}_2,B)$ are isomorphic.

To fix things, here is the definition of the Cayley graph I am working with: for a group $G$ with generating set $S$ not containing the identity, the Cayley graph $\mathrm{Cay}(G,S)$ is the graph with vertex set $G$ and edge set $\{\{ g, gs \} : g \in G , s \in S \cup S^{-1} \}$.

Comment: Your question is a little vague regarding generating sets and Cayley graphs, for example your parenthetical phrase "(as an undirected graph)" is rather mysterious. Please be explicit about the nature of generating sets and their corresponding Cayley graphs. Without that, I'm not even sure exactly what graph you have in mind for the Cayley graph of $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z_2$.

Comment: I think that when you say "the Cayley graph of $\Bbb Z \times {\Bbb Z}_2$", you mean with the obvious set of generators $\{(1, 0), (0, 1)\}$. It would be good to make that clear.

Comment: I think the statement in question is the following.
Cayley graphs Cay$(\mathbb{Z},A)$ and Cay$(\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}_2,B)$ are
not isomorphic under any choice of finite sets
$A\subset\mathbb{Z}$ and $B\subset\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}_2$.
Here $A$ is a set of generators of group $\mathbb{Z}$ and
$B$ is a set of generators of group $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: This is a very interesting question.

Comment: Apologies for the unclear question, I've edited it and hopefully everything makes sense now. My question is exactly what kabenyuk stated in their comment.

Comment: One more clarification: there's only one edge between $g$ and $gs$, because $\{g,gs\} = \{gs^{-1},g\}$, correct? That's an interesting definition, I've not seen the Cayley graph formulated in that manner.

Comment: That's true if $s$ has order $2$ yes. In general there's at most one edge between any two vertices because we've defined the Cayley graph as an abstract simplicial complex.

Comment: What partial results have you tried? For example, what generating sets for $\mathbb Z$ and for $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z_2$ have you examined the Cayley graphs for?

Comment: Aren't you also assuming that the generating sets are inverse-closed? Otherwise, the map $(a,b)\to (-a,b)$ might not be an automorphism of the graph. But then later you give the example $A=\{1\}$. Shouldn't it be $A=\{\pm 1\}$? (Also, it's not really correct to call the resulting graph "the real line".)

Comment: In the way I define the Cayley graph at the bottom, it doesn't matter that the generating set isn't inverse closed since we take edges to be $\{ g, gs \}$ for $s \in S \cup S^{-1}$.  So if $A = \{1\}$ then $\{ n, n+1 \}$ and $\{n, n-1\}$ will both be edges. And I know that it's not technically correct to call it the real line, but I don't think that causes too much confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was proved in [1] that a connected undirected Cayley graph on $\mathbb{Z}$ with finite valency has automorphism group the infinite dihedral group in its natural action. Your claim follows easily.

(By using your approach for example, fixing two points fixes everything.)

[1] Möller, Rögnvaldur G.; Seifter, Norbert. Digraphical regular representations
of infinite finitely generated groups. European J. Combin. 19 (1998), no. 5, 597–602.
MR1637768 (99i:20007), Zbl 0905.05036, doi:10.1006/eujc.1998.0210.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $S$ is a generating set of $\Bbb Z$, $G$ is the undirected graph of the Cayley graph of $(\Bbb Z, S)$, and $H$ is the corresponding graph for $(\Bbb Z \times {\Bbb Z}_2, \{(1, 0), (0, 1)\})$. And suppose $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic.

Each vertex of $H$ has degree 4, so $|S| = 2$. Say $S = \{a_0, a_1\}$. $H$ has a subgraph isomorphic to the complete graph $K_2$ on two vertices (actually, one for each ${\Bbb Z}_2$ slice), and since $G$ must have one too, we know $a_1 = -a_0$. Since $S$ generates $\Bbb Z$, $S = \{1, -1\}$. But this $G$ is clearly not isomorphic to $H$; for example, all edges of $G$ belong to some copy of $K_2$, which is not true for $H$.

So there is no such $S$.

Comment: Your graphs are not isomorphic for a very simple reason. The first graph has even degree, and the second graph has degree three. Each vertex of $H$ has degree 3.

Comment: Hmm...I was figuring that in the directed Cayley graph, $(0, 0)$ has edges coming in from $(-1, 0)$ and $(0, 1)$, and edges going out to $(1, 0)$ and $(0, 1)$. Then the corresponding undirected graph has two edges from $(0, 0)$ to $(0, 1)$. No? But the question certainly needs some clarification.

Comment: Yes I should have been more clear, I want to know whether the Cayley graphs can be isomorphic for any choice of generating sets for $\mathbb{Z}$ and for $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}_2$. The definition of the Cayley graph that I am using would only have one edge between $(0,0)$ and $(0,1)$, since $(0,1)$ is an element of order $2$, but that is not so important.